# Toggling a single element within a class when other div is clicked Jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to setup a simple comment toggle for a wordpress build.

**CSS**

```
<div class="commenttoggle">
    <p class="popcom">Show Comments</p>
                                     ~~~Clickable Button~~~~~~
</div>
<div id="comments" class="comments-area">
                                     ~~~~PHP code calling WP comments~~~
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
       $('.comments-area').hide();

           $('.commenttoggle').click(function() {
             $('.comments-area').toggle();
           });
       });
```

The above code works but when i click the show comments button under one post all the comments sections display. I've been looking over the jQuery api & here at stackoverflow but can't seem to find any advice about only toggling the element closest to the click event.

I've tried .closest & .parent but i can't seem to be able to make it work. I'd really appreciate some code but also an explanation as i'm just starting with jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.comments-area').hide();
    $('.commenttoggle p').click(function() {
        $(this).closest("div").next('.comments-area').toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah that works exactly as i wanted thank you for your time & experience

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate over element with the same class `popcom` using [each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) and apply `$(this)` to target the clicked element

```
$('.popcom').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        // Your script here              
    });
})
```

Note: `.popcom` is the class of your show comment buttons

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer really appreciated i'll see if i can get it working.