# Isotope layout back to front when accordion is displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-isotope

I've added Isotope to my project all is working fine until now.

I have implemented bootstrap accordion in to it so when the a href is clicked a div slides open to show additional information and push the second row down slightly so the content can be seen within the accordion, and when clicked again the div hides.

The issue I have is when I click the a href the first time nothing happens (it doesn't open) when I click it again (it opens, and shows the div) but it doesn't push the row below down, and when I click again (to close it) the second row gets pushed down so its back to front. I have googled this and come across this

[toggle elements in Isotope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859276/toggling-a-single-element-within-a-class-when-other-div-is-clicked-jquery)

So I tried what was suggested in the above, trigger the layout again but I have the issue I have explained above.

```
 $(function() {
        // init Isotope
        var $container = $('.isotope').isotope({
            itemSelector: '.element-item',
            layoutMode: 'fitRows'
        });
        // filter functions
        var filterFns = {
            // show if number is greater than 50
            numberGreaterThan50: function() {
                var number = $(this).find('.number').text();
                return parseInt(number, 10) > 50;
            },
            // show if name ends with -ium
            ium: function() {
                var name = $(this).find('.name').text();
                return name.match(/ium$/);
            }
        };

        // bind filter on radio button click
        $('#filters').on('click', 'input', function() {
            // get filter value from input value
            var filterValue = this.value;
            console.log(filterValue);
            // use filterFn if matches value
            filterValue = filterFns[filterValue] || filterValue;
            $container.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
        });

        $('h5:not(#nutritionInfo)').click(function() { // HERE IS THE PROBLEM
            $container = $('.isotope').isotope({
                itemSelector: '.element-item',
                layoutMode: 'fitRows'
            });

        });

    });
```

I'm trying to achieve this on the

```
 $('h5:not(#nutritionInfo)').click(function()
```

And the HTML looks like this

```
<h5 class="text-center" id="findStore">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#@item.ProductId" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="@item.ProductId" style="color: @item.ProductTextColor;font-size:19px" class="text-center">
      FIND A STORE <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
    </a>
</h5>
<div id="@item.ProductId" class="panel-collapse collapse " role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
   <div class="panel-body">
       <p>
           Content 
       </p>
        <p>
           More Content
        </p>
   </div>
```

within the above snippet, has anyone come across this behavior?

** Update **

I have just tried

```
  $('h5:not(#nutritionInfo)').on('click',function () {
            $container.isotope('reLayout');
        });
```

but the behavior still persists, can anyone think of anything else I can try?

Comment: What isotope version are you using?

Comment: @Macsupport Isotope v1.5.25

Comment: Yo0u need to make a jsfiddle or codepen with your code